# Syntax highlighter 3.0 not working on blogspot

Tags: blogspot, syntaxhighlighter

Syntax highlighter 3.0 is not working on my blog. I use the newest version right from the website. The issues are:
If I write #include  in my code, I get  at the end of it. There's no text wrapping. The blog's link is http://snacksforyourmind.blogspot.com. I also checked out options but they give nothing but bloggerMode which I already enabled. All the issues are visible in the second code from top of the page. Does anybody have some idea how to fix it?

Comment: The question is how to fix it.

Comment: Also I established that it's syntax highligher fault

Comment: How did you get it working? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your template, the SyntaxHighlighter JavaScript code may run before the content has loaded. In that case, changing the code to run after a short timeout should fix the problem. Try this in the `<head>` of your template HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
}, 10);
</script>
```

You can add further customisation of defaults before the call to `ScriptHighlighter.all()`.

If you want to customise the look and feel of the SyntaxHighlighter code display, add some CSS like this:

```
.syntaxhighlighter code {
  font-family: Consolas !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

The `!important` is necessary to override the SyntaxHighlighter theme definitions.